# Mongoose query to find match data from objectId type field

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

- **Schema for Event**

  ```
  const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
      title: { type: String, required: true },
      schedule: { type: Date, required: true },
      organizer: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user", required: true },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
  ```
- **Schema for Bookings**

  ```
  const bookingSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
      requester: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user", required: true },
      event: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "event", required: true },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
  ```

  **I want to find all the bookings by organizer id.**

I tried the below query but it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

> let bookings = await bookingModel.find({ "event.organizer": organizerId })

Comment: Can you include the code where you assign `organizerId`?

Comment: Hey @MontgomeryWatts, `organizerId` is store in `event` Schema in `organizer` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.bookings.aggregate([ 
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "events",
    localField: "event",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "event"
    }
},
{
  $match : {"event.organizer": organizerId }
},
])
```

here is the solution How I solved this. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 3 options here:

- denormalize the data and store the organizerId in the Bookings documents, so you can query it directly
- use aggregation to read every Bookings documents, $lookup the corresponding Event documents, and then filter by the organizerId
- use aggregation to $match Event documents with the organizerId, $lookup the corresponding Bookings documents, then $unwind and $project to return the just the Bookings documents.

Comment: Thanks, @Joe. Can you share any one query as an example?